Virtual machine in KVM - Creating a Bridge is "not supported"
I have a Dell Optiplex system that I am running Zorin OS on, but I have several reasons (for my homelab software, convenience, etc) to want to run a Windows device in my environment. Currently I am migrating that Windows device into a virtual machine on my Zorin device using KVM, and so far it's been pretty cool. However, the native configuration for KVM is to create a device in it's own private network, which is NOT what I need.
I had a spare NIC card (Broadcom BMC PCIe) lying around and threw that in hoping it would be an easy fix, but when I try to create a network bridge I get the following error:
Error starting domain: Unable to add bridge enp2s0 port vnet4: Operation not supported


I'm only able to guess at this point because I have never used KVM. Is this trying to add a bridge on TOP of an existing vnet? It has come up with other vnets as well (1-5) when options change. I have verified both NIC's work just fine, they do not appear to be related to the issue.
I have fully deleted the network interface and re-created it, but unfortunately no luck. I've made do so far using Macvtap, but this is not really what I want either. I want EITHER for the VM to be direct attached to the secondary NIC I added in, OR for the primary NIC on the device to serve both the host machine and the VM.
How can I bridge through the secondary NIC to the VM?

You can't use a physical NIC (enp2s0 in your case) as a bridge device - you need to create a bridge device (in the OS), add your physical NIC to the bridge, then you'll be able to use that bridge device for your network source
